# Terminal window has a glitch

Tags: gnome-terminal

My Terminal window has a glitch on the top right corner, need help on this.
Please refer the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried closing and reopening the terminal, or restarting the computer? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I have tried everything that u stated but it is still the same :(  I'm using ubuntu 17.10

Comment: This is a bug in Mutter: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/23.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/1718238 comment 8 for a possible workaround (install the gnome-icon-theme package).

Comment: @egmont Thank you so much, I installed gnome- icon theme and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to install the `gnome-icon-theme` package.